# Move data with schema change between MariaDB servers

Tags: mariadb

I am tasked with the challenge to move data between two MariaDB servers. The source database is a MariaDB 5.x, and the destination database is a MariaDB 10.x. The problem is that I need to add a column to the target.

We are splitting a monolith service into microservices. The new database needs an additional column (found in a separate table in the source database).

Is the below the way to go or are there any nicer way of moving the data?

```
SELECT CONCAT("insert into table4(id,level,name,levelt2) VALUES(",   quote(table1.id),   ",",    quote(table1.level),   ",",    quote(table2.name),   ",",    quote(table2.level),    ");") as q
       from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id 
       join table3 on table3.id = table2.table3_id
       where table3.name in ('fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum');

cat query.sql|mysql --skip-column-names --raw > table4.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write a `SELECT` statement that `JOIN` the two tables together.  Specify exactly the target columns desired (most coming from one table, one from the other table).
2. *Then* do

Something like

```
INSERT INTO new (a,b,c,d)
    SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c, y.d
        FROM x
        JOIN y ON ...
```

For reading from one *server* and writing to another, see `FEDERATEDx`.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address that the source and destination databases are on different servers. How would I do this between servers?

Comment: @mhenrixon - see FEDERATEDx.